# Sorting summarized field into bins

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a report grouping on the Finished Goods Item Number field `fg_item_numb`.  It contains the columns Fg Item Number, invoice date, invoice #, Qty invoiced.

I have created a formula field # of days invoiced, which calculates the number of days we actually invoiced each item.

```
Distinct count ({@date invoiced,{invlin.fg_item_numb})
```

I have a list of items numbers and the number of days each item was invoiced.

Now I want to sort the items into bins based on the # of days invoiced (e.g. <50, 51-100, >100).

However, Crystal won't let me calculate these using the # of days invoiced field.

Comment: Its a bit unclear....do you need to break the distict count to 50 100 and total..is this your requirement?

Comment: You can use group sorting. And you could probably handle breaks in the bins in a suppressed section if you want it to look like regular groups. Totals can be handled with formulas. Another (probably better) option is to return the number of days from sql. Which database are you using?

Comment: crystal wont let you do any condition based on a running total because it runs after the fact. Use a sql command to build your report and then a regular summary

Comment: Is `@date invoiced}` a complicated formula?